# Is "oublient" in the subjunctive in "je comprenais très bien que les gens m’oublient après ma mort"

Tags: subjonctif

This question on *oublient* as found in Book 2 chapter 5 of L'étranger by Camus, as quoted below.  If you need more context, the narrator of the passage is on death row for murder.

> C’est à un semblable moment que j’ai refusé une fois de plus de recevoir l’aumônier. J’étais étendu et je devinais l’approche du soir d’été à une certaine blondeur du ciel. Je venais de rejeter mon pourvoi et je pouvais sentir les ondes de mon sang circuler régulièrement en moi. Je n’avais pas besoin de voir l’aumônier. Pour la première fois depuis bien longtemps, j’ai pensé à Marie. Il y avait de longs jours qu’elle ne m’écrivait plus. Ce soir-là, j’ai réfléchi et je me suis dit qu’elle s’était peut-être fatiguée d’être la maîtresse d’un condamné à mort. L’idée m’est venue aussi qu’elle était peut-être malade ou morte. C’était dans l’ordre des choses. Comment l’aurais-je su puisqu’en dehors de nos deux corps maintenant séparés, rien ne nous liait et ne nous rappelait l’un à l’autre. À partir de ce moment, d’ailleurs, le souvenir de Marie m’aurait été indifférent. Morte, elle ne m’intéressait plus. Je trouvais cela normal comme je comprenais très bien que les gens m’**oublient** après ma mort. Ils n’avaient plus rien à faire avec moi. Je ne pouvais même pas dire que cela était dur à penser.

**QUESTION**

1. Is *oublient* in the indicative or subjunctive?
2. If the answer to 1 was "subjunctive," would it be ungrammatical to use a verb in the indicative in the same passage, or just not as good?
3. Conversely, if the answer to 1 was "indicative," would it be ungrammatical to use a verb in the subjunctive in the same passage, or just not as good?

**BACKGROUND**

I am expecting that the verb was in the subjunctive because the narrator is only stating what he understood to be the case, and for the purpose of the passage need not commit himself to its being in fact true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Le verbe *oublier* (1<sup>er</sup> groupe), il est au présent du subjonctif, 3<sup>e</sup> personne du pluriel !

2) Ce serait peut-être agrammatical de changer le temps puisqu'on va à l'encontre des normes de la grammaire et de l'usage du subjonctif (le souhait, le doute, la négation, la possibilité...) mais ici je pense que la narrateur exprime une **possibilité** donc on peut changer cette phrase par l'expression **qu'ils puissent m'oublier** (en restant dans le même mode). Autre chose, la majorité des verbes du 1<sup>er</sup> groupe se conjuguent de la même manière qu'ils soient au subjonctif présent ou à l'indicatif, donc pour ta réponse on ne verrait pas la différence.